# NMAP save results to separate files

Tags: nmap

I was wondering if there was any way to specify a range of IP addresses and save the scan results for each to a sepperate file in the same folder.

So scan 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3 and they all save to a file with the file name as their IP address in a folder.

I'm working on a small screen and it would really help make the results more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  However, you might want to take a look the various `-o` options.

For example, `-oM <filename>` will store it in "Machine Readable" format.  Another option is a greppable format.  Both of these might serve your purpose because, essentially, they will save the results in a file with one line per host rather than the rather verbose standard output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to read them though so if it goes all on one line I think it will be rather confusing! Is there a way to convert them from this one line format back into verbose standard output?

Comment: No no. Each host is on one line, not everything. 

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, but even if I wrote a small program to split each line up into separate files, is there a way to turn that one line of a host back into verbose standard form?

Comment: Not from nmap but it is very easily parsed. There is no way to do what you ask unless you drive the entire scan from a script, invoking nmap with different options each time.

Comment: Oh that's a really good idea, I could write a script that takes the nmap arguments, copies then but splits up the IP ranges and does a scan for each one, creating a separate file, what a fun little project. You genius! Thank you!

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Where in God's name did you find a reference to `-oM`? That option name has been [deprecated for over 15 years](https://nmap.org/changelog.html#2.54BETA6).

Comment: @bonsaiviking You pick up a lot of old facts in thirty years.